# Error 3075 - Syntax error

Tags: ms-access, vba

My code crashes on following code when I write

```
" ***and LaDate=#"" & Format([LaDate] - 1, ""mm/dd/yyyy"") & ""#"")) = 0))*** As C "
```

What is wrong with the above code?

```
SELECT LaTable.Num, LaTable.LaDate,((DCount(""LaDate"", ""Latable"", ""Num="" & ""[num] "" " _
& " ***and LaDate=#"" & Format([LaDate] - 1, ""mm/dd/yyyy"") & ""#"")) = 0***)) As C " _
          & " FROM LaTable " _
          & " WHERE (((DCount(""LaDate"", ""Latable"", ""Num=" _
                   & "[num]  and LaDate=#"" & Format([LaDate] - 1, ""mm/dd/yyyy"") & ""#"")) = 0)) " _
          & " ORDER BY LaTable.Num, LaTable.LaDate;
```

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements which would avoid many of the pitfalls causing your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
"SELECT LaTable.Num, LaTable.LaDate, Count(*) As C " & _
"FROM LaTable " & _
"GROUP BY LaTable.Num, LaTable.LaDate " & _
"HAVING Count(*) = 0;"
```